# How to insert the value in cell in tableview at particular indexpath?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitableview, xcode4.2

I have a label and textfield in tableview, now what I want is whatever value I insert in textfield  in textfieldDidEditing method it should calculate the value and return it to the label in that indexpath for tablevievw.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do get indexpath of cell in while editing textfield?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In textfieldDidEditing, you can get the cell of the corresponding textfield, calculate value and assign it to label as follows:

```
yourTableViewCell *cell = (yourTableViewCell *)[[textField superview] superview];
cell.yourLabel.text = value;
```

Comment: i have one cell in which i have subview the label,and i am not able to call cell.labelname.text

Comment: Whatever be the hierarchy, you can get cell from your textfield if it is the subview of your cell.You can use above method(superview) to get cell, you just have to identify hierarchy of your views.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* u just give Tag to TextField and in textFieldDidEndEditing, save textfield text into an string and then reload the row...here is the code..also have sample */


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];

    UITextField *txtField1 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 100, 80)];
    txtField1.tag = indexpath.row;
    txtField1.delegate= self;
    [cell addSubview:txtField1];

    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 100, 80)];

    [cell addSubview:label1];

    //set text in label ** str1 comes from textFieldDidEndEditing
    label1.text = str1;

    return cell;
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //save textField text to any string**declair it global
    str1 = textField.text;

    //reload selected row in table
    NSIndexPath *durPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:textField.tag inSection:0];
    NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:durPath];
    [tbl reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
}
```